# caption below long table with specific spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, longtable, subcaption

I have to add caption below the long table and with 12pt empty space before and after the table caption. Help me in this regard.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{jucs2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[letterspace=-50]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9} 

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

\usepackage[textwidth=8cm, margin=0cm, left=4.6cm, right=4.2cm, top=3.9cm, bottom=6.8cm, a4paper, headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[format=plain, labelfont=it, textfont=it, justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{microtype}
 
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}


\urlstyle{same}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\jucs{{Journal of Universal Computer Science}}
\newcommand\jucsvol{vol. 27, no. 1 (2021)}
\newcommand\jucspages{2987-2989}
\newcommand\jucssubmitted{1/1/2021}
\newcommand\jucsaccepted{2/2/2021}
\newcommand\jucsappeared{3/3/2021}
\newcommand\jucslicence{ CC BY-ND 4.0}
\newcommand\startingPage{2987}
\setcounter{page}{\startingPage}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{| p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.35\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth} |}

\hline
{Author} & {Purpose} & {Description} & {Relative Findings}   \\ 
\hline                 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
{Author} & {Purpose} & {Description} & {Relative Findings}   \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
 \captionsetup{font=small}
    \caption{\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont{\itshape{Review Summary of Dashboard Designing}}}
    \label{table1}

\endlastfoot

\end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was too lazy to download jucs2e, but this should otherwise fix the problem.

In section 3 (page 4) the manual describes how `\caption` works in longtable, which I used to better control the actual caption and avoid `\noalign` errors.
`\caption@caption` is the caption package version of `\caption` and `\captionof` simply defines `\@captype`.  Note that tables (position=above) reverse the use of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.

Finally, there is some ambiguity about the gap below the caption, so I added an `\hline` and an `\hrule` after the caption.  This shows the gap between the caption and the bottom of the table and the gap below the bottom of the table (`\intextsep` IIRC).  Adjust `\abovecaptionskip` as needed.

Also, I reduced `\tabcolsep` in order to fit the tabular inside the margins.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{jucs2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[letterspace=-50]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9} 

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

\usepackage[textwidth=8cm, margin=0cm, left=4.6cm, right=4.2cm, top=3.9cm, bottom=6.8cm, a4paper, headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[format=plain, labelfont=it, textfont=it, justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{microtype}
 
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}


\urlstyle{same}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\jucs{{Journal of Universal Computer Science}}
\newcommand\jucsvol{vol. 27, no. 1 (2021)}
\newcommand\jucspages{2987-2989}
\newcommand\jucssubmitted{1/1/2021}
\newcommand\jucsaccepted{2/2/2021}
\newcommand\jucsappeared{3/3/2021}
\newcommand\jucslicence{ CC BY-ND 4.0}
\newcommand\startingPage{2987}
\setcounter{page}{\startingPage}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr (0.05\textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth)/8}% columns totol 0.95\textwidth
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.35\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth} |}

\hline
{Author} & {Purpose} & {Description} & {Relative Findings}   \\ 
\hline                 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
{Author} & {Purpose} & {Description} & {Relative Findings}   \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline \multicolumn{4}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{%
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{12pt}% applied above caption
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{12pt}% applied below caption
    \expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{table}% use caption package
    \csname caption@caption\endcsname{Review Summary of Dashboard Designing}
    \label{table1}}}\\
    \hline
\endlastfoot
some & text & added & here
\end{longtable}
\hrule% show extra space at bottom
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me.